# Do conditions have to be wrapped in individual {} when used with $or or $and in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Will this:

```
db.restaurants.find( {borough: "Bronx", $or: [ {cuisine: "American"}, {cuisine: "Chinese"}  ] } )
```

and this:

```
db.restaurants.find( {borough: "Bronx", $or: [ {cuisine: "American", cuisine: "Chinese"}]} )
```

be considered same?

**Does individual bracketing matter in $or or $and?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this :

```
{ cuisine: "American", cuisine: "Chinese" }
```

It's not a limitation by MongoDB, even in programming languages it's mostly the same thing. Think of it this way, we're actually providing objects to MongoDB queries. So if you attempt to create an object like above - it would always pick `cuisine: "Chinese"` cause it's the second one with same key `cuisine`. That means an object ideally won't hold two keys with same name(same reason why `arrays` do exists - multiple `items`/`objects` in an array can hold same key name). Eventually you'll end-up with :

```
{cuisine: "American"}, {cuisine: "Chinese"} // two objects
```

But in MongoDB, you might not need to use `$or` & `$and` - if working on same key name :

`$or` to `$in` :

```
{ cuisine: { $in : ["American", "Chinese"] } } // or operation
```

`$and` to `$all` :

```
{ cuisine: { $all : ["American", "Chinese"] } } // and operation
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P1PSyw6uF_j)